# User inputs a function argument in r

Tags: r, user-input

I'm trying to accept as an argument of a function the user input but i have trouble making it work. My actual code is this:

```
t.student.2code <- function()
{
  f <- readline(prompt="Select column group A:")
  y <- readline(prompt="Select column group B:")


  t.test(f,y)



  }
```

Normal t.test

```
t.test(beaver1$time,beaver1$temp)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  beaver1$time and beaver1$temp
t = 19.399, df = 113, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 1144.924 1405.387
sample estimates:
mean of x  mean of y 
1312.01754   36.86219
```

Using beaver1$time and beaver1$temp as arguments in my function it doesn't work

```
Error in t.test.default(x, y) : not enough 'x' observations
Inoltre: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(x) : si è prodotto un NA per coercizione
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want as input. Please provide an example of what you want users to input and what you want as output. From your code above, I've assumed f and y should be numeric vectors.

Comment: Do you always use the same data frame or will you pass that in as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks okay. Note that readline() returns strings, so the function t.test must accept two string parameters.

Simple example:

```
testinp <- function() {
  c1 <- readline()
  c2 <- readline()
  sum(as.numeric(c1), as.numeric(c2))
}
```

In case you man `t.test` from the stats package, passing strings won't work as it expects numerical vectors. Maybe you want to specify variable names like the example below?

```
c1 <- c(1,2,3)
c2 <- c(2,4,5)
testinp <- function() {
  tmp1 <- readline()
  tmp2 <- readline()
  t.test(get(tmp1), get(tmp2))
}
testinp() # enter "c1" and "c2"
```

To handle the example your question:

```
testinp <- function() {
  c1 <- readline()
  c2 <- readline()
  t.test(eval(parse(text=c1)), eval(parse(text=c2)))
}
testinp() # enter "beaver1$time" and "beaver1$temp"
```

Comment: So i have to write in the t.test as.string(y) for example?

Comment: no, I was imprecisely: R has no strings as such, they are actually character vectors (I will continue to call them strings just for brevity). Nevertheless, you have to convert it only if the method does NOT take string arguments. How does the t.test method look like? And which errors do you get?

Comment: You're not going to do a t.test with two scalars??

Comment: using the beaver1 dataset in r when using as input beaver1$temp and beaver1$time in my function it doesn't work while in a normal t.test it works

Comment: what do you enter for the readline() calls? When you enter variable names maybe you are looking for get()? t.test(get(c1), get(c2))

Comment: try this: t.test(eval(parse(text=c1)), eval(parse(text=c2)))                              (it should work, but there are probably nicer solutions)

Comment: This answer doesn't deal with columns (in a data frame) though. And you really don't need to resort to eval(parse(...))

Answer (score 0):

```
# default data frame (df)

f <- c(1,2,3)
g <- c(3,5,6)
df <- data.frame(f,g)

tfunc1 <- function() {
    print("Available column names:")
    print(names(df))
    col1 <- readline(prompt="Enter column 1 name:\n")[[1]]
    col2 <- readline(prompt="Enter column 2 name:\n")[[1]]

    t.test(df[[col1]], df[[col2]])
}

tfunc2 <- function(localdf) {
    print("Available column names:")
    print(names(localdf))
    col1 <- readline(prompt="Enter column 1 name:\n")[[1]]
    col2 <- readline(prompt="Enter column 2 name:\n")[[1]]

    t.test(localdf[[col1]], localdf[[col2]])
}

tfunc1()
[1] "Available column names:"
[1] "f" "g"
Enter column 1 name:
f
Enter column 2 name:
g

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  df[[col1]] and df[[col2]]
t = -2.5298, df = 3.4483, p-value = 0.07459
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -5.7875506  0.4542173
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 2.000000  4.666667 

tfunc2(df)
[1] "Available column names:"
[1] "f" "g"
Enter column 1 name:
g
Enter column 2 name:
f

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  localdf[[col1]] and localdf[[col2]]
t = 2.5298, df = 3.4483, p-value = 0.07459
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.4542173  5.7875506
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 4.666667  2.000000
```

Comment: i'm actually trying to let the user select a column

Comment: I want this: R asks for column a, user input x$a; r asks column b, user input x$b, R then calculate t.test(x$a,x$b)